# Empty DataTextField property of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` that is bound to `sqlDataSource`. Part of the SQL query is:

```
"Select (firstName +" "+ SecondName +" "+ LastName) AS Name"
```

`DataTextField` property of the `DropDownList`  is set to `Name`.

The problem is: if any of (`firstName`, `SecondName`, and `LastName`) equal to `NULL`, the `DataTextField` property become empty.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just check if the string is null and if so, assign it a value, either `""` or `"no name"`, etc

Comment: @Enfyve Your solution will not display the name at all. What I need is: for example, if the database row has only first and last name, I still want the name displayed in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this. You have to check for NULL values and replace them with an empty string. Finally I replace 2 spaces with 1 in the replace function to account for empty SecondNames.

```
SELECT REPLACE(ISNULL(firstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(SecondName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName, ''), '  ', ' ') AS Name
```

Comment: This puts an additional load (albeit small) on the database, why not check for a null or empty string on the query's result?

Comment: Because OP wants results even if any of the 3 columns is NULL. Empty string in asp.net is not the issue here.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I was misinterpreting the problem to be 'any of the queries', and not 'any of the selectors.'

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for.